# How to add a random value from one table to another Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hi there fellow programmers

I am stuck at the moment. I have two tables and want to add a random value from the one table into another. Oracle syntax has made it kind of impossible and can't find another way. The only way the two tables link is through a column called location. I want to add random IDs that exist in the one table into the User table. Here is what I came up with thus far

```
UPDATE USERS u
SET LINK_ID = ( 
                SELECT s.ID FROM
                ( 
                  SELECT l.ID, l.location
                  FROM LINKS l
                  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.value 
                ) s
                WHERE ROWNUM = 1
                AND UPPER(u.location) = UPPER(s.location)
              );
```

This is so close but not yet there. The problem with this solution is after I run `AND UPPER(u.location) = UPPER(s.location)` the SQL order the records by the location thus removing the random function.

I even tried moving `UPPER(u.location) = UPPER(s.location)` to

```
 ( 
   SELECT l.ID, l.location
   FROM LINKS l
   WHERE UPPER(u.location) = UPPER(l.location)
   ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.value 
 ) s
```

but I then get an error reading: "U"."LOCATION": Invalid Identifier

So I guess the U table loses its value if you create to many subqueries
If you know of a solution please help and thank you for your time

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You could use `merge`.  But using the syntax that you have, you can use the `keep` method:

```
UPDATE USERS u
SET LINK_ID = (SELECT MIN(l.ID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.value) 
               FROM LINKS l
               WHERE UPPER(u.location) = UPPER(l.location)
              );
```

That way, you don't need an additional subquery, and Oracle syntax works.

Note:  12g supports `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY`, which also obviates the need for the subquery.

EDIT:

Another method to get a random value for ordering is to hash:

```
UPDATE USERS u
SET LINK_ID = (SELECT MIN(l.ID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ORA_HASH(l.location || l.ID)) 
               FROM LINKS l
               WHERE UPPER(u.location) = UPPER(l.location)
              );
```

Note:  I haven't actually used hashing in Oracle for this purpose, so this is a little speculative.  Also, this will be a stable assignment (meaning that you'll get the same value each time) unless you add a random-ish seed assignment.

Comment: The problem is after the WHERE Clause is executed, the SQL orders the records by location which takes only the first rows of the randomized records. Thanks 12g sounds great but we have a Professor that will penalize us if we don't use 11g.

Comment: @SandMan . . . The `order by` with `keep` is executed *after* the `where` clause.  This version should not have the issue that you have with your version (and your issue is really that `order by` in a subquery is not guaranteed to return anything in order, except for the use of `rownum`).

Comment: I see why I thought there is an error. Here is the problem with the sql statement. If I declare MIN(l.ID) then it will always return the same ID ( which is the minimum ) thus each records had the same l.ID.

Comment: @SandMan . . . That is not how `KEEP` works.  You can use `MAX()` if you prefer.  The aggregation function is overridden by the `DENSE_RANK` clause.

Comment: Well something is wrong because each user that lives in say Ney York has the same id and each user that lives in Miami has the same ID but is different from New York. This was the same error I had with my SQL. Also its not because I have one record of each in the link table just checked.

Comment: @SandMan . . . What happens if you run the subquery (without the `WHERE` clause)?  Does the same location get different ids? This might be a case of Oracle optimizing too far.  I wonder if `ORDER BY l.location, DMS_RAND.value` would fix the problem, in that case.

Comment: I tried running it without the `WHERE` clause but then the users that live in New York might get Link ID's from Miami and that is the purpose of the `WHERE` clause. I tried `ORDER BY l.location, DMS_RAND.value` but then all the users get the same Link ID.

Comment: same error. Haha I will just have to add them manually I guess. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @SandMan . . . The hashing method also doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, but I think it is because Oracle does not run the query for each record but only run the query once, store the value and use it for each record

Answer (score 0):

This is a modification of Gordon's query that should work:

```
SET LINK_ID = (
    SELECT MIN(l.ID) 
           KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.value || u.link_id ) 
    FROM LINKS l
    WHERE UPPER(u.location) = UPPER(l.location)
);
```

The trick is here: ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.value **|| u.link_id**

This prevents Oracle from optimizing the query, 
because it forces to reevaluate the expression for each record from `users` table.